# Nested scss rule not rendering in react project

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I may be missing something blatantly obvious, but for some reason when I try to nest sass rules, nothing renders. However, every other aspect seems fine.

In this case, hover isn't working.

jsx:

```
const SidebarSection = (props) =>
 <div className={styles.sidebarPane}>
  <ul className={styles.navList}>
    <li className={styles.navElement}>{props.element}</li>
  </ul>
 </div>;
```

scss example rule:

```
    .navElement {
     cursor: pointer;
     margin: .5rem 0 0 0;
      &:hover {
        color:yellow;
      }
    }
```

Webpack css/sccs loaders:

```
 test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'style-loader',
  }, {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      modules: true,
    },
  }, {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
  }
```

Comment: `className={styles.navElement}`  What's going on here?  Are you passing a styles object as a prop?

Comment: yeah I'm importing styles from a Sidebar.scss class that I have

Comment: If nothing at all is rendering -- you have a totally blank page -- then you should have a console error or a network error at least.  What do you see there?

Comment: Everything is rendering fine, but the rule that I nest in another class doesn't. so if I nested with the &:foo{ color: yellow; }, the color: yellow; would be ignored but everything else would be the same as before